# Simple entity relationship redundancy error

Tags: sql, entity-relationship, redundancy

I am using ER Assistant to create my first entity relationship diagram.

I have created an entity called Users which contains the following attributes

```
UserID (identity 1,1) PK 

UserName  (varchar, 50)
```

I have created a second entity called Logs, its attributes are

```
LogID (Identity 1,1) PK

LogEntry (varchar, 256)

UserID FK
```

I have assigned it assertions as follows,

- A user can create many logs
- A log must be created by only one user

The relationship is defined as one user to many logs with user being mandatory and the logs are optional

The error I am getting is:

> "The 'UserID' attribute in the 'Logs' entity type is redundant with
>   the 'Creates' relationship.  Because 'UserID' is the primary key of
>   'Users' it should not be an attribute of 'logs'.

So my question is, if I do not place the UserID as a foreign key in the Logs table, how do i properly associate the two?  I thought I had a decent understanding of how this works but this is definitely not making sense to me at the moment. I am unsure if this is an error in the validity checking or I am actually doing this incorrectly.

Comment: don't see any issue though. looks correct. where you get that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the UserID is not a property of the Logs table (consider a Log being created by a User as well as the System, hypothetically), good design dictates that you separate out the relationship into a 3rd table:

```
UserLogs
--------
UserID
LogID
```

This way if a log is created by the System, you could create another table:

```
SystemLogs
----------
SystemID
LogID
```

And use the same entity Logs for both relations

Comment: Ok, so this definitely fixed the error. By creating the additional entity and extending out the relationship, it no longer reports an error.  However, I am still kind of confused on how to evaluate this... or maybe its best said that i don't understand how the application evaluated it.

Comment: so correct me if I am wrong, but the LogEntry field is removed from Logs and added to each of the subordinate entities?  finally, I definitely understand how breaking that out makes for a more robust design, however i am still stuck on understanding the difference between the UserID being in one and not other.

Comment: No, LogEntry is a property of the Logs table and should remain there. It seems to me like you are trying to create an ER model without understanding some of its basics. I would read up on normalization - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization (including up to 4NF) to begin with.

Comment: absolutely true.  I am very new to this.  Knowing that it is normalization that I need to understand to solve my misunderstanding is exactly what I needed.  thank you

Comment: I find the Wikipedia articles and explanations to be NOT the most easily understandable source so shop around. Also if you are very new to this, I would suggest spending some time looking at things and people around you and create entity models for and relationships between them. For example, if you are at work "Room" might be an entity (what are the attributes of a room?) and "Manager" might be another (how are Manager and Room related?) A good ER modeler is able to represent real world entities and their relationships as close to reality as possible in a database.